# How to underline blank space in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am making a report that should be printable from the web browser. At the bottom is a field for the recipient to fill in, so it's underlined. I would rather not have to eyeball a certain number of underscores, and they seem to have gaps in them anyway.

What I am going for is...

Amount Paid: $ ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

So far, I have managed this CSS:

```
<div>
    <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
        Amount Paid: $ 
    </p>
</div>
```

That draws a line to the edge of the parent `div` - which I want. However, it also draws a line under "Amount Paid: $", which I don't want. Every combination of `p`s, `span`s, etc. I've thought of has failed:

If I put the text in a `span` that nukes the border, it doesn't matter, I suppose since it's still part of the `p` and the border is still drawn.

I can add the underline to a span after text, but that doesn't work. It only seems to want to underline the blank space when the border style is in the `p` element.

Likewise, if I replace the `p` with a `span` it doesn't get the memo that it should extend the border all the way:

```
<p>
    <span>Amount Paid: $ </span>
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"> </span>
</p>
```

Does nothing. The line is never drawn. If I add a letter to the second span, it's drawn under that, but no more.  And if I replace the `p` with anything else like divs or spans, it doesn't seem to work either...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have stumbled upon one of the situations where it's semantically valid, *nay* **encouraged**, to use a table. Are you working with tabular data? (ie. a series of transactions with totals).

Comment: I suppose you're right, it is tabular data... Only three lines, though. And the underline in the original report extended left beyond where the column would end, so I had discarded it rather than deal with colspans, etc... but I could give that a try as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the `display` (CSS) of the second span to `inline-block` and set its `width` (CSS).

upd:

Or try something like:

```html
<p style="width: 200px; display: table;">
  <span style="display: table-cell; width: 100px;">Amount Paid: $ </span>
  <span style="display: table-cell; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Works pretty nicely, though I do have to set the width. Was hoping to have it expand to the remaining size tag, but I could make this work.

Comment: @Andrew: in this case you can try to change the `display` s of the parent `div` and `span` s to `table` and `table-cell` respectively. Actually, recently I had a similar problem, and playing with `display`s was successful.

Comment: I decided to go with the inline-block, seemed 'purer' than throwing in table cells and I found a width that worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

This works in the year 2014.

```html
Amount Paid: $ <span style="text-decoration: underline; white-space: pre;">                   </span>
```

Comment: Advantage, it looks like normal underline (when printing, or generate PDF).  Somewhat thinner than a 1px border in Chrome.

Comment: A beautiful one-liner. Best solution

Answer (score 6):

Another one solution using `disply: flex;` and `flex-grow`:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.underline {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='label'>Count:</div>
        <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='label'>Amount Paid:</div>
        <div class='underline'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, especially for filling remaining space with underlines

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind manually specifying the width of the line, you can do this:

```
<span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding-left: 50px">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not worried about support for older browsers (IE6 generation), there's always using the min-width property to get a default amount of blank space that expands as necessary.

```
<p>
    <span>Amount Paid: $ </span>
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; min-width: 100px;"> </span>
</p>
```

Note that for IE7, you'd have to add an `overflow: visible` to the min-width element so that it treats min-width properly, as opposed to it's default (buggy) behavior of treating it as width.

Comment: It's a good answer too. But `min-width` cannot be applied until the span has `display` set to `inline-block`, at least in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Lyu True enough, though based purely on the description, he should not be limited to '<span>' tags for this, and could easily be worked around.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add non-breaking space characters like so:

```
<h1>STRONG&#160;&#160;&#160;</h1>
```

css:

```
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

add as many as you like to increase width of your underline.