# CSS border bottom after text

Tags: css

css

```
.bottomdotline{
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-width:2px;
display:table-cell;
width:100%;
}
```

html

```
<td >Name: <span class="bottomline"> <? echo $name; ?></span></td>
<td ></td>
```

How can I make the bottom border after text, if I use  next rows will be affected of the width. fyi: the php value will display on top of border

My goal:

Name:__________________

I found similar post and answer here [How to underline blank space in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513388/how-to-underline-blank-space-in-css)

But I want to use class

Comment: `.bottomdotline:after` should help

Comment: @Morpheus if i will use after, and use content, how can i use its bottom-border? tnx

Answer (score 5):

Add css:

```
.bottomline:after{
  content: " ";
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-width:2px;
  display:table-cell;
  width:200px;
}
```

Here is live example http://jsfiddle.net/aghd7/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `span` has no `width` . Easiest solution is to make it have 
`display:inline-block`
 and `min-width`

Comment: i tried to use min-width but if i use 100% it still affects the text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="offset-border">Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

And the CSS.

```
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.offset-border{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.offset-border::after{
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 6px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5000px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code.... same as example..

```css
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.underline:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="underline">Lesson Planner</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```