# Dynamic Underlining

Tags: html, css, django

Let's say I have the following section on a form

## Form Section:

Data:_____________________________________________________________________________ 
    __________________________________________________________________________________     
    __________________________________________________________________________________ 
    __________________________________________________________________________________

and I want to be able to insert {{ data }} into the section while keeping every line (even if it's unused). I'm doing this for work to replicate an old form. This form has to be **identical** and that's why I can't simply do something like:

```
<u>{{ data }}<u>
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of options here;

- Hacky: Use multiple text inputs. Style them to have a solid bottom border (as the underline) and use a bit of javascript to handle moving between them on word wrap/arrow key movement. Downside: you'll miss *something* like handling text readers properly, obscure keyboard shortcuts, etc... Also, while pasting is fairly easy, copying would be a pain.
- Use a textarea with a background-image with the lines. This relies on you locking down the font size/line spacing to look right
- Html5: look into using [contenteditable](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) attribute. you should be able to replicate the appearance fairly easily using css and divs/spans. Then make the right one editable

Comment: Yeah those were the the answers I was hoping for. Unfortunately i think I'm going to have to buckle down and go the hackish route because of the PDF renderer that's handling the page. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: If you're going to go down that route, I'd suggest you look into using a real textarea of the appropriate size hidden off-screen. Any input gets written to it and it's used to handle word wrapping and copy/paste operations. In other words, the text inputs get updated to reflect the textarea when the textarea changes. This allows you to offload as much as possible to the browser. It's also a single, canonical input to use when the form is posted back. With a little work you should be able to get it quite close

Answer (score 1):

This post might be helpful. [How to underline blank space in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513388/how-to-underline-blank-space-in-css)

In their example, you would put your template code in the first span.

Comment: That was a useful reference. Unfortunately there was an unforeseen problem with the solutions provided on that page. The HTML to PDF renderer I'm using doesn't seem to support border's on anything that's not display: block;