# How would I underline even the white space wtih css from an xml file

Tags: css, xml, whitespace

Im having trouble underlining an entire line with css. I am styling an xml file. How would I go about underlining the white space?

```
stock:nth-child(1){
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:red;
}
symbol{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:65px;
    }
company{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:60px;
}
lastSale{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:430px;
}
```

heres the xml

```
 <stock class="down">
         <symbol>AAPL</symbol>
         <company>Apple Computer, Inc.</company>
         <lastSale>$15.26</lastSale>
</stock>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to underline blank space in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513388/how-to-underline-blank-space-in-css)

Comment: Ah I was able to get a border to work finally from that thread. Thank you