# How to make centered underline on empty space?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an underline on empty spaces on center of the page like below:

[image: Example]

I want to create the line "Between____________________" and make it center like the image above. I'm able to create the underline but I'm not sure how to position it in the middle/center of the page. Below is my code (I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513388/how-to-underline-blank-space-in-css)):

```
<span style="display: table-cell; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></span>
```

How do I make the position centered? If you have a better alternative to create blank space underline, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to appear in the center of your page, just use a parent element to center it, and set it to display as an inline-block rather than a table cell.

```html
<span style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
        <span style="display: inline-block;">Between</span>
<span style="display: inline-block; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100px"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: My goal is to create underline on blank space (see title and image) not line under the words

Comment: So, to have the underline appear on the line, but not under where the words are?

Comment: I am so sorry, hopefully I got it this time.